# Best method of carrying fruits over a period of 3 days while on a trek

Tags: backpacking, food, trekking

While trekking, I prefer having fruits in the *real* form, not dried ones and no pulp or juices.

When carried without being squished fruits like apple, litchi and strawberries don't rot in a couple of days. But thats not the case for say citrus fruits like Orange, Sweet Lemon, Lemon or others like Grapes, Sapodilla, etc.

**How would you carry these fruits that can rot over a period of two days?**

One can ask a question *why carry them?* I do understand that you don't want to carry something that can rot. I am more keen about specifically Citrus fruits if not all of them are suitable, since the region I trek in, Oranges and Sweet Lemon are best suited fruits.

This question would typically limit to weather which isn't too extreme. (I agree, *extremity* differ heavily as we speak about various parts of the world, so I've simply added an ambient temperature range)

Temperature ranges: Maximum of 35 <sup>o</sup>C (95 <sup>o</sup>F) during the daylight, Minimum of 20 <sup>o</sup>C (68 <sup>o</sup>F) during early hours of the day and an hour before sunset.
7 to 10 <sup>o</sup>C (45 to 50 <sup>o</sup>F) during the night.

Comment: It's interesting how fruits seem to differ in different parts of the world. Here in Central Europe, strawberries sometimes spoil within hours after you bought them while it is possible to store citrus fruits for weeks without a problem. Looks like this is either due to different conservation techniques or because their ripening state is different when they are harvested for the respective markets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I **love** bananas and can eat a half-dozen to a dozen a day while at home. While out on the trail I try to have one or two a day. I also enjoy taking with me peaches, grapes, prunes (very good for you on-trail) and such, like yourself.

What I have always done is keep them in the middle part of my backpack. Above anything heavy that can squish them (food bag) and below things that compress well (thermals,quilt). Tend to keep them in a different food bag than my primary food bag, which just gets thrown all around and beat up a lot.

For peaches, because they are so easily damaged, I will often take sliced peaches and store them in a plastic container (ziplock type). Some may complain about the extra few grams for the plastic container, but we all make conscious decisions on what is worth what. To me, fresh fruit is important.

I have not heard of any long distance hikers (PCT/AT/CDT,etc) that have been fruitarian, but that would be interesting to see happen some day.

I am (as of time of posting) close to 600 days without meat consumption and it has been an interesting change while out on the trail. Leaving behind all of the meat based dehydrated meals and soups I use to make.

Anyway, I think the vast majority of fruit is not going to have issues "*over a period of two days*" as your question is posed. Most fruit, even in warmer conditions can be stored in the middle of your pack and not have any issues. Same method has storing hard cheese for the long haul.

Comment: The pit of the peach probably weighs as much as 5-10 ziplocks to be honest, I think your way is a weight saver.

Answer (score 2):

We have never hiked in temperatures that went up to 95 F, but we have taken oranges on much longer trips than 2-3 days, with no problem, with day-time temperatures in the low 80s, and very sunny skies.   As others have said, put the fruit in a plastic bag in the middle of your pack; it will be protected from being squashed, and insulated to some degree from the heat.

On a long trip, the last can of concentrated OJ that we opened had fermented.  OJ wine is pretty bad.